# Are the comments only for the nodes?

Tags: 7, comments

I'm thinking of making a module for Drupal 7. The main content aren't nodes, it will be in a different table. Can I use the default comment module or it is only for the nodes?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: In short, yes it is only for nodes. The database structure of the comments contains a reference to a nid (a node id). But if you don't want to put your main content in nodes, you'll lose a lot of power of the Drupal system. Can you be more specific? It might be possible with nodes after all

Comment: I want a very simple quiz module. I know that quiz module exits, but it's too complex for my purpose and also to add some functionality I want. The quiz is the node in quiz module, but I want comment every single question. But I think that one node for every question can be too slow.

Comment: It's a good idea in general not to make architectural decisions based on assumptions about performance that haven't been tested yet. This is called "premature optimization". Generally if performance is an issue it's easier to optimize something that uses software in the way intended and is therefore open to reuse of proven techniques than to do so with something that's got lots of custom code in it.

Comment: I'd go with the out of the box module. Then you can use Drupal's built in menu's, comments and all other functions. Those options will not be available when you read data from other sources.